# How to close light box form after clicking on submit button?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a light box form (and have a page in the background). I want to close the light box and stay on that page after clicking on the submit button. But it's redirecting to another page (PHP database connection page) after clicking the submit button.

I want to know how to close light box and stay on that page.

Comment: eee... show as the code.

Comment: This is not a question this is a remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the form that handles the form request and then return false from that handler and the page won't refresh. Because we don't know which lightbox you are using we can't exactly tell you how to remove it... but if you're using jQuery you could use something like:

```
$("#lightbox-id").hide();
```

or

```
$("#lightbox-id").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to submit the form within the lightbox & close the lightbox.

Answer (score -1):

```
function send_form ( )
{
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest;
if (!ajax) return false;

ajax.open('POST', '/index/send_form/'); //your post url should be here
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

var field0= document.getElementById('submit').value;
var field1 = document.getElementById('message').value; //you should modify these fields according to your form 

ajax.send('sub=' + submit + '&message=' + content);
//then post url becomes something like: www.example.com/index/send_form/?sub=submit&message=this

//then close the lightbox in here
}
```

and for the html part remove action attribute and call this function in onsubmit event.

Comment: he wanted way how to close a window, not how to post ajax request

Comment: he also wanted to stay on the form page after submit